# AngularJS DatePicker in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to get datepickers to display in a table using an ng-repeat.  I have a begin date and end date.  When I try to display both datepickers they display one over the other.  Below is my code and a screenshot of what is happening.

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="waiver in model.waivers" >
               <td class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="waiver.StartDate" is-open="waiver.isOpen" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, waiver)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="waiver.EndDate" is-open="waiver.isOpen" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, waiver)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="waiver.FuelCap" /></td>
            <td><button type="button" ng-click="updateWaiver(waiver)" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>
            <td><button type="button" ng-click="removeWaiver(waiver)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Here is a quick [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3S1gJAGDG9fEO9fFbck) example.

I know they are both opening when the open button is clicked but if you could help explain why they appear in the same column of the table.

Comment: Can you provide your `dt-options` and `dt-columns` configuration?

Comment: Those are default values that have not been configured.  That part was developed by someone else.  If I remove those values from the <table> I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with how bootstrap is styling the input-group. You need to not place that class on the td. Try moving it down a level like so:

```
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="waiver.StartDate" is-open="waiver.isOpen" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, waiver)">open</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="waiver.EndDate" is-open="waiver.isOpen" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, waiver)">open</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer, Here's the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/r9CT0gvWhiRv2OPNlPKe?p=info